# How can I solve Missing binding usage android delegate with Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, delegates, dagger-hilt

Hi I'm trying to use Android Delegate with Hilt.
But when I try it I receive an error

```
/news_api/app/build/generated/hilt/component_sources/bbc-newsDebug/com/newsapi/NewsApiApp_HiltComponents.java:146: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.support.domain.usecase.MyDelegate cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements NewsApiApp_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
  
  Missing binding usage:
      com.support.domain.usecase.MyDelegate is injected at
          com.features.ui.home.MyViewModel(…, myDelegate)
      com..features.ui.home.MyViewModel is injected at
          com.features.ui.home.MyViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.bbrustol.newsapi.NewsApiApp_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.newsapi.NewsApiApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.newsapi.NewsApiApp_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

I tried to add a bind

`@Binds abstract fun bindMyDelegate(myViewModel: MyViewModel): MyDelegate`

But it shows me another error

```
error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements NewsApiApp_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      com.support.domain.usecase.MtDelegate is injected at
          com.features.ui.home.HomeViewModel(…, myDelegate)
      com.features.ui.home.MyViewModel is injected at
          com.features.di.BindViewModelModule.bindMyCaseDelegate(myViewModel)
      com.support.domain.usecase.MyDelegate is injected at
          com.features.ui.home.MyViewModel(…, myDelegate)
      ...
  
  The cycle is requested via:
      com.support.domain.usecase.MyDelegate is injected at
          com..features.ui.home.MyViewModel(…, myDelegate)
      com.features.ui.home.MyViewModel is injected at
          com.features.ui.home.MyViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.newsapi.NewsApiApp_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.newsapi.NewsApiApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.newsapi.NewsApiApp_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

MyViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val myUseCase: MyUseCase,
    myDelegate: MyDelegate
) : ViewModel(), MyDelegate by myDelegate {
... 
...
...
}
```

MyDelegate

```
interface MyDelegate {
    fun <T, R> GenericUsecase<T, R>.call(
       ...
    )
}

@Singleton
class MyDelegateDefault @Inject constructor() : MyDelegate
```

Any clue to solve it?

Ps.: My code works with Dagger but not with Hilt.
Dagger version: com.google.dagger:dagger-android: 2.45

Hilt version: com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.47

In the Dagger project, I don't need to bind my interface.

Comment: You can't do that. To create an instance of MyViewModel you need an instance of MyDelegate. Hilt needs to know how to create MyDelegate. Your binding method doesn't make sense since creating MyViewModel itself needs a MyDelegate and then creating a MyDelegate needs an instance of MyViewModel. It's somehow a circular dependency.

Comment: I tried to follow this sample of delegate
https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/delegation-pattern

If i use inheritance it works. But I'd like to use delegation.

ps.: I have a default Instance in MyDelegate. I forgot to add it here, sorry :(

Comment: So you need to bind your MyDelegate interface and provide a MyDelegateDefault. This way dagger can inject it into the VM